# How to deploy SSIS package to Azure?

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, azure-storage

guys.
I know it is a general question. Let me give you my scenario:
I have a client who sends a bunch of Excel files to me and I use my on-premise SSIS package to export it to a database located on Azure. My SSIS package does call stored procedures stored on the Azure SQL Server to manipulate the data.

I want to move the whole process to the cloud and I want to know what is the best way and how can we achieve it. I was thinking maybe I can use blob storage in a container and by providing a cloud folder located on Azure and let my client through the files there. Then my an app (service) such as Data Factory can detect those files and run my SSIS package that is deployed on Azure "Somehow".

Any ideas or sample code would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try below manual approach -
    1. Copy all csv files to ADLS (Azure Data Lake Storage) (For Automation - Copy activity, for loop and lookup activity, you may use)
    2. For any transformation of data, use USQL jobs (ADLA) whose output is also stored in ADLS. You can save USQL scripts in blob storage (for ADF AUTOMATOMATION).
    3. To transfer the data from ADLS files to Azure sql database, use copy activity of azure data factory and use sql as sink and csv as source format.